# ssh with passphrase

Tags: ssh, passphrase

ssh user@host works (in a script via Apple Terminal)

does anybody know an easier way than ssh-agent to combine the passphrase with the ssh command ?

regards

Comment: You mean, be prompted to enter the passphrase for an authentication key? If so, `ssh -i path/to/my/key user@host`.

Comment: Belongs to http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
sshpass -p password ssh user@host
```

However if you wanted the luxory of not typing in your password, I would HIGHLY suggest setting up public/private ssh keys:

http://www.ece.uci.edu/~chou/ssh-key.html

and http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

This is extremely secure, and very convient.

Comment: The OP actually seems to be using private keys, as he mentions passphrases, not passwords. Also, ssh-agent probably caches private keys so users don't have to repeatedly type passphrases...

Answer (score -1):

For scrub just take a look to the configuration files of your installation of open ssh, cause you'll find every single option you can include or deactivete while you connect to the server. There is an option of fusemount for example if you'd like to have your machine conneted to the one in which you're logging in ( i used it with my netbook when they were REAL netbook and not computers). Fusemount is an option when you want more abilities to be added to you computer or you need data from both sides (the one of the server and the one of the client) but security cannot be omitted in any case.